# Exoplayer video does not scale when SurfaceView is scaled

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) library to create video player application. I'm trying to make a feature like youtube: drag video player to bottom and i will be scaled to smaller size. To do that, i have used [ViewDragHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html). When player is dragging, i scale it size like this:

```
public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) {
            mTop = top;

            mDragOffset = (float) top / mDragRange;

            mVideoView.setPivotX(mHeaderView.getWidth());
            mVideoView.setPivotY(mHeaderView.getHeight());
            mVideoView.setScaleX(1 - mDragOffset / 2);
            mVideoView.setScaleY(1 - mDragOffset / 2);

            mDescView.setAlpha(1 - mDragOffset);
            requestLayout();
        }
```

`mVideoView` is a `SurfaceView`, and player take `SurfaceView` to render it content. The `SurfaceView` scale correctly but it's content doesn't.

**Question: how can scale SurfaceView and it's content too?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, i have found a solution for my question. I used `TextureView` instead `SurfaceView`, now it worked perfect.

Comment: Could you explain how you applied your solution? I am trying to do exactly the same thing (YouTube player like player) but I cannot understand where do I set the TextureView option. Also if you could share your work I would really appreciate it.

Comment: How to animate parent view of exoplayer?. If I add "surface_type" = "texture_view" work perfectly. But set default "surface_view" means not working for animation.

Comment: HI, without textureView, how to animate an exoplayer parent view?.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TextureView` instead of `SurfaceView` like this:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/play_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:surface_type="texture_view"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late as an answer, but another solution would be to wrap the SurfaceView with a FrameLayout. Then modify the layout params or the correct properites of the FrameLayout instead of directly modifying the SurfaceView.

Note: a custom Layout can also be used and in some cases might be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick with SurfaceView because you're using a third party library or whatnot, a workaround would be to scale it down using the scale animation and AFTER the animation has finished, update the layoutparams of the SurfaceView by giving the the correct size and position to where the scaled position is. It's not perfect, but should be good for those who have no other choice.